# Definition of the $O$ category for Kac Moody algebras

Tags: representation-theory, definition, lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras

In Carter's book "Lie algebras of finite and affine type", he defines the $O$ category for Kac Moody algebras as follows:

[image]

I do not understand in what sense $\lambda<\lambda_i$ on the last part of the definition: I thought it just meant that $\lambda(h)<\lambda_i(h)$ for all $h\in H$, so that we were demanding the set of weights to have a supremum with respect to this relation $<$. But in that case one would always only need a single $\lambda_i$ (*i.e.* $s=1$), so I highly doubt that my interpretation is correct.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: I don't have the book handy so I cannot check. But presumably he has defined the partial order previously. I don't recall what subtleties are introduced when moving from semisimple to Kac-Moody, but the semisimple case has the order be defined by the difference being a non-negative integral sum of positive roots.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ok, that would make more sense since that order is only partial, so that we may need $s>1$.